# codeigniter blank page, no errors or logs

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was working on an existing project of codeigniter 3.0.1 and I must have change something somewhere that I dont find who broke the site. Everything was working before and now I get a blank page with no errors and no logs at all...

I have added the code to the index.php to display error and still nothing

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

I then started to put some echo to see where i reached... Index reach to

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

system/core/CodeIgniter.php reach to

```
$EXT =& load_class('Hooks', 'core');
```

system/core/Hooks.php reach to

```
    $CFG =& load_class('Config', 'core');
```

And then nothing can be echo from /system/core/Config.php within the constructor. I can still echo from before the class definition.

I picked a fresh copy of that file to be sure it's good and still same.

Can anyone help me identify the issue or point me out some ideas, I am not so used to CI. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an error in a php syntaxe in some page. I post this answer because of the way I ended up troubleshooting it... For some reason, I was totally unable to get the error messages from anywhere (log or php_error) even with the error_reporting or the ini_set() even if i placed it mostly everywhere even the page where the error was.

The problem about no error reporting came from the php config that I didnt had acces to, but I managed to downgrade the php version from 7 to 5.6 and errors showed up letting me find the file with bad php syntaxe.

Hope that might help someone